# html onclick javascript function call to show something

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call gettotal function to get value from textbox and * 3 and show the result in other textbox , code does not work
where is the problem!?

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function gettotal()
{
    var x=0;
    x=document.getElementById("pop").value*3;
      document.getElementById("pop1").innerHTML="<b>"+x+"</b>";

}

</script>
<title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
<input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="get" OnClick="gettotal()"/>
<input type="text" id="pop" name="pop"  size="3"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="pop1" name="pop1" size="5" value="val"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the specific "not working" issue you are encountering? Are you getting any errors in your browser developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function gettotal()
{
    var x=0;
    x=document.getElementById("pop").value*3;
      document.getElementById("pop1").value=x;

}

</script>
<title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">
<input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="get" OnClick="gettotal()"/>
<input type="text" id="pop" name="pop"  size="3"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="pop1" name="pop1" size="5" value="val"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **[.innerHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/innertHTML)** (used to asign HTML tags to element) use `.value` to assign value to an input field like @Azzi mentioned in his answer :

```js
function gettotal()
{
  var x=0;
  x=document.getElementById("pop").value*3;
  document.getElementById("pop1").value=x;

}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type="button" id="btn" name="btn" value="get" onClick="gettotal()"/>
  <input type="text" id="pop" name="pop"  size="3"/> 
  <input type="text" id="pop1" name="pop1" size="5" value="val"/>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.